# glue PostgreSQL connection: “Unable to find suitable security group”

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I am trying to add a new RDS connection for a PostgreSQL database. I am trying to follow [this post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html) to make this set up, but when trying to add the security group in the source field from inbound rules I get this message: `You may not specify a referenced group id for an existing IPv4 CIDR rule`. If anyone has any idea about how to solve this I would really appreciate your help.

Security group inbound rules:
[image]

Security group outbound rules:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the corresponding rule and adding the rule again with the source as the Security Group Id solved the problem. Not sure exactly why !